# busybox: watchdog - logging

Tags: busybox, watchdog

I'm trying to debug a reboot of an embedded device and suspect watchdog might be involved but cannot find any logs.

I also cannot find the watchdog.conf anywhere.

The device is available at `/dev/watchdog`

Does watchdog log events to anywhere? Can I make it?

I've also read that it I should be able to find out if the last boot was the result of a watchdog restart via `ioctl` using the flag `WDIOC_GETBOOTSTATUS` but I can't figure out how to run that from shell.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have the exact same problem.

I think [this](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/ioctl) can help much.

This is the missing tool to call arbitrary ioctl on devices.

Since most of data associated with ioctl are not human readable, this tools is intended for driver developpers who want to do quick tests on their drivers.

Usage:

> ioctl [OPTIONS] FILEDEV IOCTL_NUM